# curl to php code

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I have the following code :

```
 curl -X PUT -u "<app key>:<secret key>" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{"alias": "myalias"}' \
    https://go.xxx.com/api/device_tokens/<token>/
```

I tried to convert it to php but it seems not working and i don't know what is the problem.

this is what i tried

```
    <?
       $token = $_POST["token"];
       $al =  $_POST["alias"];
       exec('curl -X PUT -u "_rEUqXXXmSVEBXXuMfdtg:vpB2XXXXX_2HZ_XXXX7t-Q" \
         -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
         --data \'{"alias": "'.$al.'"}\' \
         https://go.xxx.com/api/device_tokens/'.$token'/');
?>
```

Comment: There is a curl library in PHP. (-1 because you never specify what are the error, another make people guessing question)

Comment: I think your end-of-line backslashes should be removed (assuming you are allowed to use exec to run curl).

Comment: @pritaeas I tried without it and not working

Comment: Have you tried to output for example `curl --help > help.txt`  If that doesn't work, you're not allowed to do this, or you need to specify the path to curl. If that also fails, use ajreal's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    // echo $url; die;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("custom: header")); 
    $returned = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

There are many more options to do what you want in the [PHP docs](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), don't they help.

Comment: I linked to the appropriate part on php.net